# Simulate Notepad in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, notepad

I have a Silverlight 5 application that I am running out of browswer. I was able notepad it a separate window. That was fairly easy.

```
Dim shell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Shell.Application")

shell.ShellExecute("notepad.exe") 'Open notepad
```

The problem I have is how to I paste content into the notepad window. If this is not possible then how do I simulate the functions of notepad in Silverlight? I currently have the content I want it a multiline text box. The users want the ability to select all and paste into another windows. Also they want to set the cursor to a particular line number within the file or search for certain text.

Answer (score 0):

On my system (Windows 8), notepad.exe will open a filename passed as an argument.  So I suppose you could write your data to a file and pass that filename as an argument to Notepad.  A quick googling didn't reveal any other command-line options it takes, but there may be some.